# $\frac{df}{dz}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, $z=x+iy$

what is the difference between $\frac{df}{dz}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

I understand $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$
and

$\frac{df}{dz}(a)=\lim_{z\rightarrow a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}$ where $a$ is complex, but I don't understand intuitively how they could be different. What is being kept constant when we write  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Comment: There's no difference. $f$ is a function of one variable, namely $z$; therefore $\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.

Comment: Are my eyes deceiving me or are the quantities in question the same? Or as you asking about the conjugate variable?

Comment: @Demosthene But if I have $f(z)=x-iy$ then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$ and yet $f$ is not constant so $\frac{df}{dz} \neq 0$

Comment: @Snickett : you cannot write $f(z)=x-iy$, but $f(z,x,y)=x-iy$ ; Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=1$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=i$

Comment: @Snickett : if $z=x+iy$  then $f(z)=f(x+iy)$ . which leads to 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{d f}{d z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{d f}{d z}$$  $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{d f}{d z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=i\frac{d f}{d z}$$